# Drawing to screen without X Windows System

Tags: bitmap, vga

On PCs running MS-DOS we used to be able to write to the screen using bitmapped graphics by issuing instructions via the BIOS INT 10h system calls. Is there a similar method with Linux, without using X11? Fundamentally, how does X11 achieve the same?